# Module XML with SQL field (JFormFieldSQL) - Custom Form Field - Check if table exists

Tags: module, xml, form-fields-types

My module uses the sql field (JFormFieldSQL) for a few simple queries in the database for a 3rd party component. My concern is that if the tables are missing, opening the module in the admin will "crash" the back-end, because of the error in the mysql (not finding the table).

Is there anyway to have the module in the backend checking if the table exists in db and if not to throw a notification that the necessary table is missing, and not continue loading the xml ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your concern is justified. Indeed, if there is an SQL error, the backend of the module will crash.

If this is a must have for you, I would look into extending the `JFormFieldSQL` with a custom implementation where you can check for SQL errors or do a MYSQL check like  `SHOW TABLES LIKE 'mycomponenttable'`

See [How to create a custom form field type in a module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197236/how-to-create-a-custom-form-field-type-in-a-module)

Answer (score 1):

You can just check if the extension is enabled at the top of the module mod_.....php to prevent any further processing:

```
// Check for component
if (!JComponentHelper::getComponent('com_....', true)->enabled)
{
....
    return;
}
```

Comment: Hello Anibal, I have already this code in my module and it's only for the front-end, it's not applying for the admin of the module. The module will still be crashed, because of the error in the sql of the JForm SQL field.

Comment: But probably it could be used inside the custom field, to check for the component.